# How to get from Mumbai Airport to the CST Station?

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, mumbai, bom

What is the cheapest way to get from International Airport to the Mumbai CST? Which are the other options (not so cheap, but I suppose more comfortable)?

Comment: Maybe, but this is our first trip to India so I don't have an idea about how to pay for this. I don't want to pay 3 times the price, even if this is still cheap :)

Comment: No, I have to take a train at night

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cheapest (that's not walking or hitchhiking) is to take an autorickshaw to Andheri train station (50 - 100) rupees, followed by a train ride to Churchgate (7 rupees), from which you can walk or take a taxi (40 rupees?) to CST.
However, this is quite cumbersome and very time consuming. Expect this to take two hours total.

The prepaid taxi booth at the airport will charge you no more than 550 rupees to get you to CST. That's, what, 7 euros? The convenience is more than worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Take auto-rickshaw from airport to Andheri( around 100 rupees)
Then take local from Andheri to Mumbai CST(only 10 rupees)

Comment: And how long will this take? The other answer estimates about 2 hours for autorickshaw-train-taxi.